# Is there a way to check if user is pressing the enter go to next line key?

Tags: java, keyboard, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

I want to be able to save an `edittext` when the user clicks the enter inside the android keyboard.

The `edittext` data that I am trying to save is inside a `tablerow` as shown below

[image]

There are only numbers (double format) and as shown above there can be multiple rows in which the **keyboard** is affected by this e.g. if there is one row or the last row, the keyboard will display a **tick button** as shown below

[image]

In this case the **code** that I am currently using will work and save the data perfectly fine however, if there is another row below this e.g. if I try to edit the **top row first** the keyboard will look like this

[image]

in this case it wont work and it will go to the next line until I have clicked that tick button and then it will work.

Is there a way I can target that specific key and save as soon as the user clicks enter or leaves that edit text field?

My current code (this is the part were the enter key is being checked)

```
est.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Enter pressed");

            Double damageCost = 0d;

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(est.getText())) {
                damageCost = est.getCleanDoubleValue();
            }
            Log.d("COST", String.valueOf(damageCost));

            if(ds.size() == 0){
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please add damage to the vehicle to edit price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                        est.setText(nf.format(vehicle.getTotal()).substring(1));

                        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                a.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(a.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    }
                });
            }

//                                    Code for the action you want to proceed with.
            for (int d = 0; d < ds.size(); d++){
                Damage damage = ds.get(d);
                if (ds.get(d) == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                for(int ve = 0; ve < vehicleUpdate.size(); ve++) {

                    Vehicle vehicleUp = vehicleUpdate.get(ve).vehicle;

                    if(vehicleUp == null){
                        continue;
                    }

                    if(String.valueOf(damage.getVehicle()).equals(String.valueOf(vehicleUp.getUuid()))) {
                        Log.d(" DAMAGE UUID", String.valueOf(damage.getVehicle()));
                        try {
                            vehicleUp.setTotal(Objects.requireNonNull(damageCost));
                            vehicleRepository.update(vehicleUp);
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e){
                            Log.d("null", "null");
                        }

                    }
                    est.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(true);
                }
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        a.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(a.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
});
```

Comment: You can try adding `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` to your edittext and adding a check for that in your `EditorActionListener` in lieu of the `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`.

Comment: I did `est.setImeOptions(actionId);` inside `setOnEditorActionListener` but I do not know how to check on that in `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`, I did tested it but it didn't work.

Comment: Try setting `est.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` right before the code to set the listener.

Comment: That actually did the trick, thanks a lot!